# Piped output from Python gets backed up

Tags: bash, python, jq

I have a Python program which prints json objects (from intermittent messages from a game's API). When I run the program by itself, each message immediately appears in the console output.

```
$ python myprog.py
{"SG_MSG":{"obj_id":"SD748","aspect":"0","time":"42"}}
{"SG_MSG":{"obj_id":"SD748","aspect":"6","time":"75"}}
```

But when I pipe the output into jq, jq outputs nothing for ages, and sporadically spits out a bunch of messages at once:

```
$ python myprog.py | jq .
```

I've tried prepending each message with the record separator character (ascii 30) and using `jq --seq .` but the result is the same.

Piping to `od` shows the record separator character is appearing as the jq manual says it should:

```
$ python myprog.py | od -t d1
… … … 125 125 10 30 123 … …
```

which is }, }, LF, RS, {

And piping to `od` shows the same behaviour, where no output is shown until a bunch of messages have backed up.

I'm guessing there's something elementary about bash I'm overlooking here…?

Comment: You are not flushing your output buffers.

Comment: Add `sys.stdout.flush()` calls to your Python script, or use the `-u` argument to the Python interpreter, or set the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`. This isn't a bash problem, *or* a jq problem, but [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) provides useful background for understanding it.

Comment: (Buffering stdout when not to a TTY is default behavior for *the standard C library*, so it impacts *all* programs written in C that don't go out of their way to override it, no matter whether they're invoked from bash or not).

Comment: Thanks! But why doesn't it buffer when outputting to console, then?

Comment: @JackDeeth, see, in my prior comment, the caveat "when not to a TTY" -- the console is a TTY (in the sense that the [`isatty()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html) returns true). The assumption is that when something is writing to a TTY, it's being read by a user who wants to see things immediately (and couldn't keep up with the kind of high-speed stream of data that large buffers optimize for anyhow), and thus that latency is more important than throughput. This is why the `unbuffer` command, f/e, operates by *emulating* a TTY.